# router registration order influences output

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am facing a strange issue trying to implement a webservice using django rest frameworks. I have this two APIs - one for getting the list of news based on category(provided as URL parameter) and another to get the details of a news provided the news ID(provided as url parameter). Following is my app's `urls.py` code:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
...
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('news_contents', NewsContentViewSet)
router.register('news_infos', NewsInfoViewSet)
router.register('categories', CategoryViewSet)
router.register(r'^articles/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)', NewsItemViewSet, base_name="NewsInfo")
router.register(r'^articles/(?P<news_id>\d+)/details', NewsDetailViewSet, base_name="NewsInfo")

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The above code on calling:
http://localhost:8000/rest/articles/categoryname
returns the correct output, but calling:
http://localhost:8000/rest/articles/4057/details/
returns the following:

```
{"detail":"Not found."}
```

But when I change the order in which these two APIs are registered, both APIs start to work as expected.

Working `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
...
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('news_contents', NewsContentViewSet)
router.register('news_infos', NewsInfoViewSet)
router.register('categories', CategoryViewSet)
router.register(r'^articles/(?P<news_id>\d+)/details', NewsDetailViewSet, base_name="NewsInfo") #brought to above the listing API
router.register(r'^articles/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)', NewsItemViewSet, base_name="NewsInfo")

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Why is this happening? I am getting a feeling that as I add more APIs, whatever the reason behind this is going to get me stuck.

Another thing I noticed while debugging this was that, there are plenty of other endpoints which I don't want are automatically getting listed as available endpoints:

```
Using the URLconf defined in restnews.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
rest/ ^news_contents/$ [name='newscontent-list']
rest/ ^news_contents\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='newscontent-list']
rest/ ^news_contents/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='newscontent-detail']
rest/ ^news_contents/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='newscontent-detail']
rest/ ^news_infos/$ [name='newsinfo-list']
rest/ ^news_infos\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='newsinfo-list']
rest/ ^news_infos/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='newsinfo-detail']
rest/ ^news_infos/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='newsinfo-detail']
rest/ ^^categories/$/$ [name='newsinfo-list']
rest/ ^^categories/$\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='newsinfo-list']
rest/ ^^categories/$/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='newsinfo-detail']
rest/ ^^categories/$/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='newsinfo-detail']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<news_id>\d+)/details/$ [name='NewsInfo-list']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<news_id>\d+)/details\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='NewsInfo-list']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<news_id>\d+)/details/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='NewsInfo-detail']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<news_id>\d+)/details/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='NewsInfo-detail']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)/$ [name='NewsInfo-list']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='NewsInfo-list']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='NewsInfo-detail']
rest/ ^^articles/(?P<category_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='NewsInfo-detail']
rest/ ^$ [name='api-root']
rest/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
```

I have only provided 5 end points and all the remaining ones are not needed and hence need to be removed. Are these issues somehow connected? How can I solve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the combination of ModelViewset and DefaultRouter class behave. From the [DRF Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), it provides a bunch of end-point ***by default*** 
 which is very very handy if you are doing [**`CRUD` Operations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).
From your description, I understood that you are not dealing with **`CRUD`** operations, and hence you can't use the **Magic** of the `DefaultRouter` and `ModelViewset`.

So, What I suggest is, use **`rest_framework.views.APIView`** class for your purpose.

**`Example`**

```
views.py
```

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyViewClass(APIView):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):  # This fucntion will handle your "HTTP GET" requests
        # put your logic here
        return Response(data={"mymsg": "this is my response"})

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response("This is post method")
```

and in your `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'mysample/', MyViewClass.as_view())

]
```

**References**
1. [DRF Router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routers)
2. [DRF viewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)
3. [DRF APIview](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)

**UPDATE-1**
Read the Django [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

> How Django processes a request
>
> When a user requests a page from your
>   Django-powered site, this is the algorithm the system follows to
>   determine which Python code to execute:
>
> 1. Django determines the root URLconf module to use. Ordinarily, this is the value of the ROOT_URLCONF setting, but if the incoming
>      HttpRequest object has an attribute called urlconf (set by middleware
>      request processing), its value will be used in place of the
>      ROOT_URLCONF setting.
> 2. Django loads that Python module and looks for the variable urlpatterns. This should be a Python list, in the format returned by
>      the function django.conf.urls.patterns().
> 3. **Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.**
> 4. Once one of the regexes matches, Django imports and calls the given view, which is a simple Python function. The view gets passed an
>      HttpRequest as its first argument and any values captured in the regex
>      as remaining arguments.
> 5. If no regex matches, or if an exception is raised during any point in this process, Django invokes an appropriate error-handling view.
>      See Error handling below.

Comment: Currently I am using ModelViewSet, I need to change that?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't remove those *auto-generated urls* if you are using `Router` and  **if you are not using the router**, you have to manually put all the URL patterns, which is a kind of **reinventing the wheel**

Comment: Is your api provides **`CRUD`** functionality?

Comment: I just started learning Django yesterday and not so familiar with all the options such as CRUD and all. Even if the other URLs are auto generated by router, what is the reason behind the order issue?

Comment: Sure, let me check

Comment: Yes, I guess that was causing the issue, two similar URL patterns and the additional URLs which got added to that was causing the router to redirect to one of the automatically added URL schemes instead of the desired one.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Anyway, use `APIView` class if you are not performing **CRUD** operation. (my opinion :) )

Comment: Sure, first let me look into what CRUD is. I am frontend guy, just putting my head into backed technologies. SO pretty new with all these terms.